# how can I get the total count of same name of different columns in one table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

Here is the example of my question.

[image]

In the ID table, there are two columns, one is `id1` and another is `id2`.

I just want to know the total id count in `id1` and `id2` columns, like the right table.

In that situations,
How can I get the total count of same name of different columns in one table in MySQL code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `union all` to generate a single column with all the IDs, and then count them:

```sql
SELECT   id, COUNT(*) 
FROM     (SELECT id1 AS id FROM mytable
          UNION ALL
          SELECT id2 AS id FROM mytable) t
GROUP BY id
```