# Why do I get wrong count of same values in two SQL table columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with game results. Two columns are for the player names. A player's name can occur in both of these columns. On counting, how often a particular player has had a duel, I get wrong duel counts. This is a simplified description, to keep the focus on the issue.

This is my table *results* with the duels happened so far:

| player1 | player2 |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | Bob |
| Christine | Daniel |
| Daniel | Christine |
| Christine | Daniel |
| Esme | Franz |
| Esme | Daniel |
| Garrey | Hans |
| Hans | Garrey |

What I want to get is, how often the same name appears in both columns. Please note here, Garrey and Hans have a correct duel count of 2:

| player | duels |
| --- | --- |
| Daniel | 4 |
| Christine | 3 |
| Esme | 2 |
| Garrey | 2 |
| Hans | 2 |
| Franz | 1 |
| Alice | 1 |
| Bob | 1 |

My real table and SQL statement is more complex to calculate other statistics, so I need  two SELECT combined with a UNION, like I'm using in this example here too:

```
SELECT 
  playerName AS playerName, 
  SUM(duels) AS duels 
  FROM ( 
    SELECT player1 AS playerName, 
    COUNT(player1) AS duels
    FROM results 
    GROUP BY player1 
    UNION 
    SELECT player2 AS playerName, 
    COUNT(player2) AS duels 
    FROM results 
    GROUP BY player2 
  ) AS A 
  GROUP BY playerName 
  ORDER BY duels DESC
```

The problem now is, that I get wrong duel count for Garrey and Hans - 1 instead of 2:

| player | duels |
| --- | --- |
| Garrey | 1 |
| Hans | 1 |

If I would add one more result for Garrey and Hans to my table, then my SQL statement would return a duel count of 3 correctly.

Here is a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4613877b3f870bf7428ec3039a145171).

What I'm doing wrong here? To my understanding, I'm trying to count names in first column, then in the second one, and then sum up both counts. I tried a different way by using Count(*) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67548315/how-can-i-get-the-total-count-of-same-name-of-different-columns-in-one-table-in), but that made all results being wrong.

For any feedback many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unpivot and aggregate.  You can just use `union all` for this:

```
select player, count(*)
from ((select player1 as player from results) union all
      (select player2 from results)
     ) p
group by player
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: Hm, unfortunately this works in my simplified example above only, but breaks up the rest of my real case. And I still wonder, why my own SQL statement from above is not working in the case of Garrey and Hans, but for the others.

Comment: @Ravelli we can only answer the question that's asked; so you'll need to edit your question and show what else is happening in the query `:-)`

Comment: @Ravelli . . . This answers the question you asked here.  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question with appropriate explanation, sample data, and desired results.  Invalidating answers is not polite.

Comment: Sorry, but I already spent some hours in writing my question above, don't know how I should do it better, and it us pretty exhausting. Showing the full code would probably make it even more complicated. My why-question is not answered yet, since I still don't know, why my own SQL statement is not working. I already mentioned in my question, that the Count(*) solution does not work for my case.

Comment: @Ravelli trust me I really do know how much effort it takes to ask a question (I've asked a lot), but if we don't know what's happening we can't factor that into what's happening on your exact scenario. Try breaking the query into parts and checking which parts are required to cause the problem. I do symapthise with your time spent but as mentioned, if you can't add more clarity than "this doesn't work on the real case" but you can't provide the real case, how can we solve your question?

Comment: @Martin: "Try breaking the query into parts and checking which parts are required to cause the problem." This is exactly what I did. And my question has been, "Why do I get wrong count...?" Because I want to understand, "why" my "part" presented does not work, in exactly the way as I have posted it. I did not ask for a different solution.

Comment: @Ravelli sorry I misunderstood. -- you said `this works in my simplified example above only, but breaks up the rest of my real case. And I still wonder,` so you implied the answer here didn't work in your real query, but no one here will be able to tell you *why* it didn't work in your real query until you show us the query, that was my point. Anyway, not to worry, `:-)`

Comment: @Martin Still, my question refers to my simplified SQL statement posted above only. I never asked for my real one. Serving me alternative ways does not answer my question - the question is in the header, in the URL, and I repeated it in every comment. It begins with 'why', not with 'how'.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT player1, COUNT(player1)duels
FROM(
select player1 from results
UNION ALL
select player2 from results)t group by player1
order by COUNT(player1) desc
```